# Embedding Julia in C#

Tags: c#, julia, embedding

I pulled code from [here](https://gist.github.com/ihnorton/0cbe2ed595d539e859c4) related to this [post](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8931) on Github, but it does not work for me.

I'm running Windows 10, Visual Studio 2012, and my julia directory is c:\julia-0.4.3\bin.  I made a small change to the code to reflect my paths:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("libjulia.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void jl_init(string julia_home_dir);

        [DllImport("libjulia.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void jl_eval_string(string str);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Pass

            jl_init(@"C:\Julia-0.4.3\bin");

            // Crash
            jl_eval_string("print(sqrt(2.0))");

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program in Visual Studio I get:
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

If I copy the ConsoleApplication1.exe file to c:\julia-0.4.3\bin and run it from the cmd line I get:
Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.jl_init(String julia_home_dir)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)

Am I doing something wrong, or perhaps Windows 10 is the culprit?  I'm a bit new to C#, so there may be something obvious to a more skilled programmer here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

that cos you are loading a 32 bit lib into a 64 bit exe or vice versa

Try going to the project properties and turning off 'prefer 32 bit'